# Simple html COPY and PASTE problem - copies button also

Tags: javascript, html, copy, paste

Sorry for the hastiness of this post I'm in a rush. I have coed below that just functions in an HTML file. It copies fine but when I paste it pastes the copy button with it. If you go to this link  and earase all the css that mimics the problem Im having. Any help = thankshttps://codepen.io/ryanbuckley13/pen/gpyrwe

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the post.

Comment: no, the copy is done without the button (FireFox Linux)

Comment: In most places it doesnt paste the button but I'm pasting it into the TinyMCE text editor and there it adds the button. Does anyone have a code solution? Or just a way using javascript and HTML to copy text with a button without using the id in div tags, and that also doesn't paste the button?